# Error after deploying Ratpack application Heroku

Tags: heroku, gradle, groovy, ratpack

I have a Ratpack application which I am attempting to deploy on Heroku. I am deploying through snap-ci, this says passed when I click to deploy to Heroku. However in my error logs I get this error:

> 2017-02-12T15:41:19.016616+00:00 app[web.1]: bash:
>   build/install/Football-Prototype/bin/Football-Prototype: No such file
>   or directory 2017-02-12T15:41:19.117897+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from starting to crashed

My procfile file is as follows:

```
web: build/install/Football-Prototype/bin/Football-Prototype/
```

And this is my project structure.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong in my Procfile file? I followed the Ratpack instructions from their website. The react files get built into a JS and CSS file and included in the resources of my Ratpack project so I don't think this will have an effect.

Comment: Do you get an error? Your _"error message"_ didn't look like an error

Comment: Sorry i've edited the error now